# Too many "ands" in one sentence create ambiguity

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, oxford-comma

> *Cloning must be researched and funded, however, its human involvement must be limited to prevent a veritable onslaught of ethical and legal battles, and promote its potential health and societal benefits.*

Am I right to feel like there is something wrong with the sentence above?
Something with the number of "ands" and comma use, right?

Comment: To just tweak the sentence: (1) remove commas after however and battles; add "to" before promote.  But, what do they mean by "human involvement must be limited"?  Do they mean tinkering is OK up to N cell divisions or what?

Comment: @ab2- I think the clones do all the work themselves. The humans just check in from time to time to see how things are going.

Comment: An unremarked problem with the excerpt is that in the phrase "its human involvement" _its_ refers to _cloning_; but "cloning's human involvement" means what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust your feelings.  First of all, the author got two independent clauses connected by *however*.  Using the commas misleads the reader into thinking the word is just an adverbial aside.  Use a semicolon to emphasize that it's a conjunction:

> Cloning must be researched and funded; however, ....

The author has written himself into a corner.  He can't leave out the comma after battles, since it will mislead the author into parsing another object of the preposition *of*, but retaining the comma will mislead the reader into expecting another independent clause.  I think the best you can do short of a complete rewrite is add the missing *to* from *promote* to emphasize that there's a modifier of compound infinitives

> ... its human involvement must be limited to prevent a veritable onslaught of ethical and legal battles and to promote its potential
>   health and societal benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the real problem that the sentence is ambiguous? You could interpret it as saying that human involvement must be limited and must promote [...] or as saying that the involvement must be limited to prevent [...] and to promote [...]. Right? It seems to me that no one here has taken the first possibility into consideration.